# SQL Developer: Navigation Filter showing unwanted objects under Other Users

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

we went through http://www.vitalsofttech.com/top-13-preferences-to-tweak-when-using-sql-developer-4/ and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#RPTUG41429 for Database: Navigation Filter settings and followed steps to remove everything else but tables, procedures and packages, which works well for the user/schema we're logged-in. But form the same logged-in user, if we go to other users and select a different schema/user, then it also shows OLAP Option and Scheduler options in the navigation filter(apart from the desired tables, procs and packages), even though they(OLAP Option and Scheduler options) have been unchecked in the Oracle preferences. Is this a known issue or are we missing something?

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

my SQL developer version: 4.1.3.20, build main-20.78

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 4.2.0.16.356 - hides scheduler anyway, I don't see OLAP anyway in my DB... Which version are you seeing this in?

Comment: My Bad Alex, should have mentioned in the original question(edited now), i am using 4.1.3.20, build main-20.78